# Must a man that is unable to obtain an erection follow the laws of shomer negiah?

Tags: halacha, negia

For a man that is unable to have an erection (and ergo unable to have relations) must they follow the laws of shomer negiah (lo tikr'vu "don't draw near to nakedness"), or is the "drawing near" to reveal nakedness primarily *only* in situations where it can lead to actual relations? Does it matter if the halacha is like the Rambam or Ramban (d'oraissa or d'rabannan respectively)?

(This is a follow up to the question: [Yichud with someone who can't have an erection](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26067/yichud-with-someone-who-cant-have-an-erection))

Comment: Why the commentless downvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R. Waldenberg (Tzitz Eliezer [vol. 6 p. 230](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14505&st=&pgnum=239)) brings the opinion of R. Yehudah Navon that even according to Rambam there would not be even a rabbinic prohibition since physical contact, in this situation, can not lead to the illicit biblically forbidden act. But, it is nonetheless detestable to breach such limits and engage in physical contact despite it not leading to "uncovering nakedness". TE then argues that even according to opinions who would prohibit it on a rabbinic level would hold so when there is physical contact which is obviously prohibited.

Finally, TE concludes that such seclusion should be avoidable unless unavoidable and not left to others' suspicion.

Comment: "that even according to opinions who would prohibit it on a rabbinic level would hold so when there is physical contact which is obviously prohibited."  This isn't exactly readable. Consider revising.